# How to create a link in XMLUI, with search and filter parameters?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, user-experience, dspace

I am having problems creating links in XMLUI, I created a link that returns a simple order:

```
<a href="discover?query=&submit=Buscar&filtertype_0=subject&filter_0=&filter_relational_operator_0=equals&rpp=10&sort_by=dc.title_sort&order=asc"></a>
```

but when I try to run, returns me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `&` characters in the href as `&amp;` so that they will be parsed correctly.

```
<a href="discover?query=&amp;submit=Buscar&amp;filtertype_0=subject&amp;filter_0=&amp;filter_relational_operator_0=equals&amp;rpp=10&amp;sort_by=dc.title_sort&amp;order=asc"></a>
```